# Package Required: rtl160.bpl

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, package

I'm currently using delphi xe2. well the firemonkey part of it. I use to be able to compile and test my project. I tried the tested version on win xp and it needed the rtl160.bpl package, so I added it. Now it is failing to compile even on my machine. I keep getting errors saying

> [DCC Fatal Error] E2202 Required package 'rtl160' not found

...even after i removed it from the packages, so can anyone help me please fix this problem ?

Edited Afterwards.
It seems to complile on my machine once I unchecked "Link with runtime packages" but still doesn't run on win xp
[image: Screenshot from settings]

Comment: There were only two spelling mistakes -- you're doing fine, better than most.  If you do encounter people giving you grief over this on SO, use the flag function to alert the mods.

Comment: Not quite sure, but one thing I can point out is make sure you change the "Target" drop-down above to "All Configurations" before making these changes, unless you intend to only apply this change to 32-bit Debug configurations.

Comment: If you want us to help solve errors, you must tell us what the errors are. "It doesn't run" offers few clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay cool so I solved the problem, it was actually an error on my part, if delphi cant seem to find the package make sure that the run time packages aren't linked to the compiled packages

You can check the settings of your application in delphi by pressing ctrl + shift + F11

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Environment variables.
Platform should been AnyCPU

Comment: Platform should **not** be `AnyCPU`. There should be no `PLATFORM` environmental variable; the IDE will set it at compile time based on the target you're compiling for at that time. Also, that has nothing to do with this question anyway.